# Tokyo Tyrant transaction support

Tags: c, api, client, transactions, tokyo-tyrant

I've noticed that rufus-tokyo and other apis support transactions in Tokyo Tyrant. I couldn't find any mention of the transaction support in the TT docs (http://1978th.net/tokyotyrant/spex.html#clientprog)

Is that transaction support simulated? Or is there a way to do a server-side transaction using the C api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Tokyo Cabinet that [supports transactions](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html).